# Validate AD User Credential from External PC via Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

Is there a way to validate the user credential that the user key in from two textbox (username, password) against the Active Directory User Lisst of the network of the web server?

For example I have a user account, User1 and the password is U1. The User1 is included in the domain for example DomainServer so it would be DomainServer\User1.

Now I need to create a web application that will allow me to login using my user credential. I need to validate if the username I key in exist in the network of the web server and if the password is correct. Assuming that i accesses that web application via External Machine (machine not included in the web server network) for example a machine from Internet Cafe. Lets assume that the web application was hosted and the URL is www.company.com\ValidateCrendential

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Please visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx , you may get some logic ...

Answer (score 0):

If you web server is in domain then you can use LDAP to validate the user credentials.

```
    public bool Authenticate(string userName,string password, string domain)
{
    bool authentic = false;
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain,userName, password);
        object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
        authentic = true;
    }
    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException) { }
    return authentic;
}
```